# How to run code over a certain period of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import time
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time-price'
r = requests.get(url).json()

start_price = {'MSFT': 0, 'AAPL': 0,'AMZN': 0,'PYPL': 0,'GOOGL': 0,'TSLA': 0,'FB': 0,'DIS': 0,'TD': 0,'NVDA': 0,'V': 0,'NFLX': 0,'WMT': 0,'ADBE': 0,'CM': 0,'NKE': 0,'DELL': 0,'TWTR': 0,'NSU': 0,'KO': 0,}
end_price = {'MSFT': 0, 'AAPL': 0,'AMZN': 0,'PYPL': 0,'GOOGL': 0,'TSLA': 0,'FB': 0,'DIS': 0,'TD': 0,'NVDA': 0,'V': 0,'NFLX': 0,'WMT': 0,'ADBE': 0,'CM': 0,'NKE': 0,'DELL': 0,'TWTR': 0,'NSU': 0,'KO': 0,}

now = time.time()
future = now + 10

while time.time() < future:
    for x in r['stockList']:
        current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        if current_time[11:16] == '20:55':
            if x['symbol'] == 'MSFT':
                msft_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['MSFT'] = msft_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
                aapl_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['AAPL'] = aapl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AMZN':
                amzn_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['AMZN'] = amzn_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'PYPL':
                pypl_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['PYPL'] = pypl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'GOOGL':
                googl_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['GOOGL'] = googl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TSLA':
                tsla_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['TSLA'] = tsla_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'FB':
                fb_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['FB'] = fb_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DIS':
                    dis_price = (x['price'])
                    start_price['DIS'] = dis_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TD':
                td_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['TD'] = td_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NVDA':
                nvda_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['NVDA'] = nvda_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'V':
                v_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['V'] = v_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NFLX':
                nflx_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['NFLX'] = nflx_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'WMT':
                wmt_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['WMT'] = wmt_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'ADBE':
                adbe_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['ADBE'] = adbe_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'CM':
                cm_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['CM'] = cm_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NKE':
                nke_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['NKE'] = nke_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DELL':
                dell_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['DELL'] = dell_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TWTR':
                twtr_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['TWTR'] = twtr_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NSU':
                nsu_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['NSU'] = nsu_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'KO':
                ko_price = (x['price'])
                start_price['KO'] = ko_price
        elif current_time[11:16] == '20:56':
            if x['symbol'] == 'MSFT':
                msft_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['MSFT'] = msft_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AAPL':
                aapl_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['AAPL'] = aapl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'AMZN':
                amzn_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['AMZN'] = amzn_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'PYPL':
                pypl_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['PYPL'] = pypl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'GOOGL':
                googl_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['GOOGL'] = googl_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TSLA':
                tsla_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['TSLA'] = tsla_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'FB':
                fb_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['FB'] = fb_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DIS':
                dis_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['DIS'] = dis_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TD':
                td_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['TD'] = td_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NVDA':
                nvda_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['NVDA'] = nvda_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'V':
                v_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['V'] = v_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NFLX':
                nflx_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['NFLX'] = nflx_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'WMT':
                wmt_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['WMT'] = wmt_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'ADBE':
                adbe_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['ADBE'] = adbe_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'CM':
                cm_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['CM'] = cm_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NKE':
                nke_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['NKE'] = nke_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'DELL':
                dell_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['DELL'] = dell_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'TWTR':
                twtr_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['TWTR'] = twtr_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'NSU':
                nsu_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['NSU'] = nsu_price
            elif x['symbol'] == 'KO':
                ko_price = (x['price'])
                end_price['KO'] = ko_price

print(start_price)
print(end_price)
```

Okay so this is my stock market app basically and what I want to do is to check the prices of certain stocks when the market opens and closes. In order for me to check this through I would need to run this code over a certain period of time. I tried to use time.time() and another variable future which is 10 seconds after the current time. The while loop is to check the stock prices over that time but for some reason, the while loop is infinite and doesn't exit the loop ever. How can I make it so that I check the price of each stock perhaps every hour or so?

Comment: Those huge if/else blocks can be replaced simply with `start_price[x['symbol']] = x['price']`

Comment: i would highly recommend using [cron jobs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) for time based tasks

Comment: You only ever make one request up front, so you're only ever going to get one set of prices.

Comment: The loop that you show should end as expected after 10 seconds.  Are you sure that this is the exact code you are running?

Comment: yeah its that same py file im running I also tried it on vscode and idle but both don't exit the while loop.

Comment: @Samwise so I should add another request so that I can get the price for both the starting and the closing?

Comment: Maybe?  Your start/end conditions are pretty suspicious as well.  I think it's better to chuck all of this code and start from scratch.  If you just want to get two data points, you don't need a loop at all, and per 0x5453's comment you can throw out all of this code that steps through each symbol one by one.  This whole script should be about five lines long; I'd just write it out if I had a solid idea of what exactly it was supposed to be doing.  Stock quote APIs will just give you open/close information without you having to scrape it.

Comment: most apis i think have that option but the api's aren't update like 2 days old or are paid which is why I am trying to scrape it. Also this is like the first time I wrote this so its not really polished but yeah I still need to figure how to check both timings regardless if I rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/is-the-market-open

and look for the property : isTheStockMarketOpen

if isTheStockMarketOpen is true -> the market is open